# trying to get property of non-object in php array

Tags: php, arrays, json

i am getting problem to decode this string in to array

```
$json_array = json_decode($_POST['time_array'],true);

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($json_array); $i++)
        {
            $day = $json_array->day; 
            $start_time = $json_array->start_time;
            $end_time = $json_array->end_time;

            $insert_time="INSERT INTO `nesbaty_working_time` (`provider_id`,
                                              `day`,
                                              `opening_time`, 
                                              `closing_time`, 
                                              `time`, 
                                              `status`) 
                                              VALUES ('".$provider_id."',
                                              '".$day."', 
                                              '".$start_time."',  
                                              '".$end_time."',  
                                              '".$date."',
                                              '".$status."')";
            mysqli_query($con, $insert_time);

        }
```

The error is to get data from array

```
 Trying to get property of non-object
```

and my array string is

```
[{"day":"Monday","start_time":"12 : 00 PM","end_time":"12 : 30 PM"},{"day":"Tuesday","start_time":"12 : 00 PM","end_time":"12 : 30 PM"}]
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($json_array)` says?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want object type return then remove `true` from json_decode like

```
$json_array = json_decode($_POST['time_array']);
```

and use index to access your returned data like

```
$day = $json_array[$i]->day; 
$start_time = $json_array[$i]->start_time;
$end_time = $json_array[$i]->end_time;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `JSON` is an multi-dimensional array. You have to access it with `index` as follows

```
$json_array[$i]['day'];
$json_array[$i]['start_time'];
```

Also note

```
json_decode($_POST['time_array'],true); // returns an associative array 

json_decode($_POST['time_array']); // returns an object
```

[Reference Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: please write in brief.@SAMIR